# Unable to insert object from another collection to a new document, created on form submit

Tags: node.js, mongodb, formidable

I am saving fields from a form into a mongo db collection using formidable.

the schema for the model ENTRY is this.

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');

const entrySchema = mongoose.Schema({

    product:{
        name:{
            type:String,
            required:true
        },
        image:{
            type:String
        },
        // document:{
        //     type:
        // },
        description:{
            type:String
        }
    },
    brand:{
        name:{
            type:String
        },
        logo:{
            type:String
        }

    },
    organisation:{
        name:{
            type:String
        },
        logo:{
            type:String
        },
        phone:{
            type:String
        },
        mobile:{
            type:String
        },
        email : {
            type:String
        }
    },
    category:{

        type : Object
        
    }


},
{
    collection : "entries"
}
)

const Entries = mongoose.model('entry', entrySchema)

module.exports = Entries;
```

now the CATEGORY field is a an OBJECT type and and I want to add an object from another collection called CATEGORIES. I will be able to findById and I want to insert it into the new document that is being saved on submission of the form.

I am trying to do this by

```
entry.category=Categories.findById({_id:fields.categoryId});
```

It's not working.. I seem to be gettind this error although I don't know if it's related to the above or something else

```
Error: key xxxx-shard-00-00.p5yeb.mongodb.net:27017 must not contain '.'
    at serializeInto (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xxxx-server/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:816:19)
    at serializeObject (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xxxx-server/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xxxx-server/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:947:17)
```

Could anyone advise me on how I can manage this?

Comment: whether your `fields.categoryId` value contains a dot (.) in it?

Comment: here's the view of the fields returned
```{
  categoryId: '60f3b8150c902e168a3abd72',
  productName: 'sfsdf',
  productDescription: 'sdfsdf',
  brandName: 'sdfdsf',
  organisationName: 'sdfsdf'
}```
I changed the query from a dot notation (fields.categoryId) to fields[categoryId] just in case.. but it's still the same..

Comment: Have you tried using the static value to test whether it is working or not like this: `entry.category=Categories.findById({_id : '60f3b8150c902e168a3abd72'});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are using `findById` so you only need to pass the id value instead of object:

Can you try this:

```
entry.category = await Categories.findById(fields.categoryId).exec();
```

Still, if you want to use the object you can use `findOne`

```
entry.category = await Categories.findOne({ _id: fields.categoryId}).exec();
```

You can check this documentation on [findById](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById), [findOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) and [Promises](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html)

Comment: got it.. your answer was right.. but I was trying to assign the value to entry.category as a `result` of `Categories.findById(fields.categoryId)` where the result is actually in the callback function so I needed to assign it in the callback function.. I've got rid of the error.. but I still can't assign the object CATEGORY into the entry.category.. the entry=category does not seem to work even though console.log(category) does show the right CATEGORY object.. any ideas on how I can assign the category object to the entry.object?

Comment: Yes... @AlimBolar I have updated my answer where you can use `await` & `exec()` to save the result back in variable

Comment: Thanks @HandsomeCoder ... your answer was perfect!!..:-).. As stackflow doesn't encourage long extended comments, I'll try to get it all into one comment..;-).. So await and exec() basically stop the code till it gets the result and then moves ahead.. am I right?  please do confirm if I am right.. secondly when I tried the callback function and tried to get the `entry.category=category` inside the call back function, it didn't work as the `entry.save()` was in an outer scope.. so is there a way to make it work by capturing `entry.category = category` in a callback function?

Comment: Yes... `await` & `exec()` will stop the code till it gets the result. If you want to do it in the callback then you can call `entry.save()` inside callback